# How to write shell script to create zip file for the files that had same string in file name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to write simple shell script to create zip file.
I want to create zip file by collecting files with same string pattern in their file names from a folder.

For example, there may be many files under a folder.

- xxxxx_20140502_xxx.txt
- xxxxx_20140502_xxx.txt
- xxxxx_20140503_xxx.txt
- xxxxx_20140503_xxx.txt
- xxxxx_20140504_xxx.txt
- xxxxx_20140504_xxx.txt

After running the shell script, the result must be following three zip files.

- 20140502.zip
- 20140503.zip
- 20140504.zip

Please give me right direction to create simple shell script to output the result as above.

Comment: Does it have to be in bash?

Comment: Have you tried `man zip`? I'm sure there's a way to specify a file pattern for the files to include.

Comment: Why a one-line command?

Comment: Do you know the dates or is the task to find all dates represented, and create a zip file for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *_????????_*.csv *_????????_*.txt; do
        [ -f "${file}" ] || continue
        date=${file#*_}  # adjust this and next line depending
        date=${date%_*}  # on your actual prefix/suffix
        echo "${date}"
done | sort -u | while read date; do
        zip "${date}.zip" *${date}*
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `zip` will update the archive, this will do:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *.{txt,csv}; do [[ $file =~ _([[:digit:]]{8})_ ]] && zip "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.zip" "$file"; done
```

The `shopt -s nullglob` is because you don't want to have unexpanded globs if there are no matching files.

---

Everything below this line is my old answer...

First, get all the possible dates. Heuristically, this could be the files ending in `.txt` and `.csv` that match the regex `_[[:digit:]]{8}_`:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
declare -A dates=()
for file in *.{csv,txt}; do
    [[ $file =~ _([[:digit:]]{8})_ ]] && dates[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]=
done
printf "Date found: %s\n" "${!dates[@]}"
```

This will output to stdout all the dates found in the files. E.g. (I called the previous snipped `gorilla` and I `chmod +x gorilla` and touched a few files for demo):

```
$ ls
banana_20010101_gorilla.csv  gorilla_20140502_bonobo.csv
gorilla                      notthisone_123_lol.txt
gorilla_20140502_banana.txt
$ ./gorilla
Date found: 20140502
Date found: 20010101
```

Next step, for each date found, get all the files ending in `.txt` and `.csv` and `zip` them in the archive corresponding to the date: appending this to `gorilla` will do the job:

```
for date in "${!dates[@]}"; do
    zip "$date.zip" *"_${date}_"*.{csv,txt}
done
```

---

Full script after removing the flooding part:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
declare -A dates=()
for file in *.{csv,txt}; do
    [[ $file =~ _([[:digit:]]{8})_ ]] && dates[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]=
done
for date in "${!dates[@]}"; do
    zip "$date.zip" *"_${date}_"*.{csv,txt}
done
```

---

**Edit.** I overlooked your requirement *with one line command*. Then here's the one-liner:

```
shopt -s nullglob; declare -A dates=(); for file in *.{csv,txt}; do [[ $file =~ _([[:digit:]]{8})_ ]] && dates[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]=; done; for date in "${!dates[@]}"; do zip "$date.zip" *"_${date}_"*.{csv,txt}; done
```

`:)`

Comment: +1, very exhaustive answer...but you should add a disclaimer that this is `bash4+` only due to using an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash
dates=$(ls ?????_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_???.{csv,txt} \
    | cut -f2 -d_ | sort -u)

for date in $dates ; do
    zip $date.zip ?????_"$date"_???.{csv,txt}
done
```